# can not connect to wifi with mobile

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have a modem router which outputs only a LAN cable so I used `tplink 8960N` in order to have wifi access but the problem is I can not connect to my wifi with mobiles and just my laptop can connect to it!
is this any special settings for accessing wifi with mobile devices?
how can I fix this problem?
just for more info=>
the way I have connected two modems:
1. Connect the first modem to the Internet and test it with its output(the LAN cable)
2. connect the the LAN to the WAN port of the second router(tplink 8960N)
3. and test the connection with a LAN cable from second router LAN1 port

and the mobile devices are:
- Samsung galaxy S7 edge
- Samsung galaxy J7
- Samsung galaxy S1
note: the mobile devices can discover network and also connect to that but there is no internet connection for them.

Comment: Why can't you connect to those networks? Are they detected by the phones or not?

Comment: yes they detected the network and can connect and also authenticate but there is no internet connection thru wifi!

Comment: That's crucial information which you should put in your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are three things you may want to check:

1. Make sure DHCP is enabled on your Router and you have a healthy pool
   of addresses.
2. Make sure your DHCP pool hands out a DNS address,
   otherwise no internet
3. Make sure your phones don't have a static
   address configured for a different network.  If they do, set them to
   DHCP

Comment: In which modem should I check them?

Comment: Probably on your Wireless Router.  That's where you may have your DHCP services configured. @amirsa00